# Python3 regex escape function

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

So I am given a string of digits of variable length and I need to find all possible number combinations using the digits in that string where only the digits in between may be changed, for example:

if I am given **123**, I need to find the combinations of **1x2y3 where x, y are any digits**.

if I am given **5312**, I need to find the combinations of **5a3b1c2 where a, b, c are any digits**.

I'm thinking this is possible using python's `re.escape` function, this is as far as I've come:

```
#Given the digits '123' from STDIN

#create a string "1\d2\d3"
my_regex_string = '\d'.join(input().split())

#Set x as starting point, set y as limit (not the most efficient)
x = 10**(len(my_regex_string)-1) * int(my_regex_string[0])
y = 10**(len(my_regex_string)-1) * (int(my_regex_string[0]) + 1)

while x < y:
    if bool(re.match(re.escape(p), str(x)))
        print(x)
    x+=1
```

I need feedback, does my approach make sense? Is this task doable with regex or do I need another approach?

Comment: Why don't you use `itertools`?

Comment: And why do you want to use regex?

Comment: Using regex for this is a really bad choice. Use `itertools.product`.

Comment: Are you trying to find the total number, or get a list of all solutions?

Comment: Are you looking to create a regex that can just _match_ these combinations, or to just create the combinations ? A regex would be `1\d2\d3`, etc. To generate, its just simple nested loops that you don't need anything special to do it with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, like what the wolfrevokcats said, the pythonic way of doing this is to use itertools.product function. Something like this code:

```
from itertools import product

s = input()
r = "{}".join(list(s))
c = [int(r.format(*f)) for f in product(range(0,10), repeat=len(s)-1)]
```

Comment: Really clean solution! Good job

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution using itertools, probably not the most sophisticated but it works:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = map(lambda z: [s[i] + str(z[i]) for i in range(len(s)-1)] + [s[-1]], list(itertools.product(range(10), repeat=len(s)-1)))
>>> y = map(lambda z: "".join(z), x)
>>> list(y)
```